# two navbars in bootstrap alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two nav bars, one of the nav bar has a red background and the other nav bar has blue background with multiple anchor tags.

When I reduce the screen, the second nav bar is not displaying correctly when compared to before. Can anyone help me with your best solution?
Please find issue image,

[image]

Please find my code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Header.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark navbar-custom" style="background-image:header.png;opacity:0.5;height:12vh;background-color: red"></nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm container-fluid  " style="background-color: #01adcd;">
            <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start</a> -->
            <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText"> -->
            <!-- Collapse button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
            class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>


            <!-- Collapsible content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent1" >
            <ul class=" navbar-nav mx-auto order-0" style=" background-color: #01adcd;">
                  <li class="nav-item active mt-auto mb-auto  col active">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Start.html">
                        <div class="icon-center">
                           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Start 
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon-center " >
                           <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                     </a>

                  </li>



                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Consents.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Stop
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Purpose.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           gallery
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Personal.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                        About
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Assets.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Assets
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Declarations.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Features
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Income.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Source
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Preview.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Careers
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  

                  </ul>
               </div> 
            </Div>
         </nav>
      </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my answer, is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT - By removing all my previous answer

You are facing this issue because there are too many items in your nav. So the width is too big.

You can consider **updating** the `navbar-expand-sm` class to `navbar-expand-md` in order to **change the breakpoint** on which you want the **menu collapsing** under the "burger menu".

Otherelse, you can **hide menu texts** when the **screen is small**, and add those texts into the `title` properties of your icons or its wrappers to see the "menu description" on `hover`.

Moreover, `mt-auto mb-auto col` classes for each `<li></li>` are not needed. In fact, `margin / padding` should be added only on the **wrapper**. And the navbar classes automatically arrange your items. The `col` onto your items are **breaking the responsiveness** of your nav wrapper.

### Keep `col` but updating nav to `navbar-expanded-md`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark navbar-custom" style="background-image:header.png;opacity:0.5;height:12vh;background-color: red"></nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md container-fluid  " style="background-color: #01adcd;">
            <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start</a> -->
            <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText"> -->
            <!-- Collapse button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
            class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>


            <!-- Collapsible content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent1" >
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto order-0" style=" background-color: #01adcd;">
                  <li class="nav-item col active">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Start.html">
                        <div class="icon-center">
                           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Start 
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon-center " >
                           <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                     </a>

                  </li>



                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Consents.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Stop
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Purpose.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           gallery
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Personal.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                        About
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Assets.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Assets
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Declarations.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Features
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Income.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Source
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Preview.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Careers
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  

                  </ul>
               </div> 
            </div>
         </nav>
      </header>
</body>
</html>
```

### Removing `col` but Keeping nav to `navbar-expanded-sm`:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>Example</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> -->
       </head>
       <body>
          <header>
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark navbar-custom" style="background-image:header.png;opacity:0.5;height:12vh;background-color: red"></nav>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm container-fluid  " style="background-color: #01adcd;">
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start</a> -->
                <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText"> -->
                <!-- Collapse button -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
                class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>


                <!-- Collapsible content -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent1" >
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto order-0" style=" background-color: #01adcd;">
                      <li class="nav-item active">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Start.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               Start 
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center " >
                               <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                         </a>

                      </li>



                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Consents.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               Stop
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Purpose.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               gallery
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Personal.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                            About
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Assets.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               Assets
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Declarations.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               Features
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Income.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               Source
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Preview.html">
                            <div class="text-center">
                               <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                               Careers
                            </div>
                         </a>
                      </li>
                      

                      </ul>
                   </div> 
                </div>
             </nav>
          </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

On this second snippet, I added the class `text-center` to your icon wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

After I try this code without `header.css` and `styles.css`
No have problem with your code
I will shared snippet on here
Please give the **Header.css** and **Styles.css** in here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark navbar-custom" style="background-image:header.png;opacity:0.5;height:12vh;background-color: red"></nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm container-fluid  " style="background-color: #01adcd;">
            <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start</a> -->
            <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText"> -->
            <!-- Collapse button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
            class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>


            <!-- Collapsible content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent1" >
            <ul class=" navbar-nav mx-auto order-0" style=" background-color: #01adcd;">
                  <li class="nav-item active mt-auto mb-auto  col active">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Start.html">
                        <div class="icon-center">
                           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Start 
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon-center " >
                           <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                     </a>

                  </li>



                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Consents.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Stop
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Purpose.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           gallery
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Personal.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                        About
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Assets.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Assets
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Declarations.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Features
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Income.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Source
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item  mt-auto mb-auto col">
                     <a class="nav-link navicon" href="Preview.html">
                        <div >
                           <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                           Careers
                        </div>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  

                  </ul>
               </div> 
            </Div>
         </nav>
      </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You dont need those css files.I have already written css inline.